# How can i store old and new updated value at same time?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have built a database:

```
slots(user_id,current_slots,old_slots,current_expiry,old_expiry);   
credit_transfer(transfer_id, sender_id, receiver_id,date,num_slots);  
history(history_id, reseller_id,transfer_id)
```

user_id is coming from user table.
sender_id and receiver_id are foreign keys of user_id.
reseller_id is foreign key of user table

When the user buys new slots, its entry is recorded in the history table with a new history id, i.e a from slots table.

The problem i am facing is when a new history_id is added, i.e when new slots are added, the slots with previous history id  also get updated.

How can I change the design, so that old history id row doesn't change.

Comment: Give us an example, _without_ ids, of the the table before and after "new slots" are added.

Comment: Before:
History_id      reseller_id      transfer_id           current_slots       old_slots
 1                         1                    1                          20                     10

After:
1                         1                    1                          30                   20 ,
2                         1                    2                          30                   20

the problem is slots with old history id also gets changed. how to cop that?

Comment: Do you mean that you say to change the record with, say, id=42 and the record with id=37 also gets changed for no apparent reason? If that's the case, well, databases don't just decide to update records on their own, you must have code or a trigger somewhere that's changing it. If you mean that you have two history records pointing to the same slots record and when you update slots, both history records are now pointing to the same updated record, then presumably you need to create two slots records if you need to preserve the old data, or the relevant data should go in the history record. ...

Comment: ... All told I think you need to give some more explanation of what you're trying to accomplish here. The question as it stands is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Well the simplest thing to do would be to place  a unique constraint on the userId. This would ensure that you do not have duplicates for the same user entry.

I am not sure what Language you are currently using or if you're using stored procedures. But in any case, detect the duplicate/unique constraint exception and update the slot count or expiry information.

Comment: yeah but don't want userid to b unique , there may be multiple user entries. and cant even make slots unique , since 2 users  may have same slots